# Presenting a view controller before dismissing current presented controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I need to present two view controllers with some conditions.

I will try to describe my problem, first this is what I want:

1. user tap a button on view controller 1 (call it `VC1`)
2. I present `MPMediaPickerController` (call it `MPVC`) so user can choose a song.
3. if user tap cancel, I dismiss the `MPVC` and return to `VC1`
4. if user choose a song in `MPVC` I want to present view controller 2 (call it `VC2`) under `MPVC` so when I dismiss `MPVC` the user will land in `VC2` and not `VC1`

I can't present `VC2` before `MPVC` is presented, or when `MPVC` is dismissed because than the user will see it.

I tried more sophisticated solution, like to screenshot before presenting `MPVC`, than show `VC2` with the screenshot as background (so the user wont see it, than `VC2` present `MPVC`.
This kind of work, but cause other issues so I prefer not to use this solution.

And I suppose there is no way to present a view controller under the currently presented view controller?
So I'm looking for some elegant way to solve this issue,

Comment: "I can't present VC2 before MPVC is presented, or when MPVC is dismissed because than the user will see it."
Not necessarily. You can push VC2 without animating the transition.

Comment: @marcio if I present VC2 without animation before I present MPVC, than it will be shown until MPVC will finish its animation. I dont want to present the MPVC without animation...

Comment: I do stuff like this with a container view controller. The container has a `UINavigationController` in which `VC1` and `VC2` and pushed into.  The modal is displayed in the container.  That way the user can't see any animations, but the app functions the same.

Comment: @JeffCompton you mean that VC2 and MPVC will be pushed (without animation) to a nav controller ? but than after the user finished with MPVC how can I return to VC2? pop? thats not the transition style I want

Comment: @Eyal I assumed you were presenting `MPVC` as a modal.  If that was the case, `VC1` and `VC2` are pushed to the `UINavigationController` (with or without animation).  `MPVC` is presented as a modal on your container view controller.  If you didn't want to present `MPVC` as a modal, you can swap out `VC1` and `VC2` by manipulating the `UINavigationController`'s navigation stack.  The method `setViewControllers` on `UINavigationController` should help you accomplish that.

Comment: @Eyal keep in mind that changing the nav hierarchy of the app behind the user's back might be unsettling.

Comment: I am presenting MPVC as a modal and also VC2, so I can't push VC2 with VC1 in the same nav controller.

Comment: @Eyal I don't think it's a bad idea to dismiss `MPVC` and immediately afterwards present `VC2`.  You can also present your modal as the view controller container I was talking about earlier.  This modal will have a `UINavigationController` that can be manipulated to get the transitions you want. From a design perspective, it doesn't seem to great but it'll get you the functionality you want.